# How to remove extra column headings from a .csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have written data to a .csv file but it gives me extra values for the column indexes and I cant remove them.

```
values1 = featureVectors
header1 = ["Dataset Number","Number of Sides", "Standard Deviation of Number of Sides/Perimeter",
      "Standard Deviation of the Angles", "Largest Angle"]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(featureVectors)
my_df.to_csv('featureVectors.csv', index=True, header=True, index_label=header1)
```

I have just used a few values as an example.

[What my .csv looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHqXg.png)

I need to get rid of the extra column headings(0,1,2,3) but cant figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a few lines of the csv.

Comment: I'm confused, you are trying to get rid of the extra column headings? Why is everyone suggesting `index = True` instead of `index = False`? Have you tried `index = False`?

Comment: @wwii a screengrab of the csv is in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_df.to_csv('featureVectors.csv', index=True, header=header1)
```

Comment: what is your `featureVectors` ?

Comment: Sorry i should have tagged you in the reply to @bnmalcabis below. I have fixed the problem by following this answer and then just removing my first column heading "Dataset Number" which was just the row index.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_df.iloc[:, :len(header1[1:])] \
     .to_csv('featureVectors.csv', index=True, header=header1[1:], index_label=header1[0])
```

Comment: This gives me same error as for @bnmalcabis answer, ValueError: Writing 4 cols but got 5 aliases. Your solution does work though if I remove the first column heading "Dataset Number", Thanks. I don't mind not having a column heading for my row index.

Answer (score 0):

According to `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), the parameter header recieves a list of strings or a boolean value (which is True by default).

If you pass the header list to the `header` parameter and get rid of the `index_label` parameter, it will print the colum names as you wish.

I hope this helps.

Comment: that's what @cur4so suggested which is not working as per OP.

Comment: If i do that i receive this error: ValueError: Writing 4 cols but got 5 aliases

Comment: @ThomElliott, featureVectors has 4 columns or 5 columns?

Comment: @bnmalcabis 4. I removed the column heading "Dataset Number" and it worked, I now just don't have a column heading for my row index which is ok I suppose

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the suggestions and comments to get it working. I had to do another step on top of the answers. My corrected code is:

```
values1 = featureVectors
header1 = ["Number of Sides", "Standard Deviation of Number of Sides/Perimeter",
      "Standard Deviation of the Angles", "Largest Angle"]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(featureVectors)
my_df.to_csv('featureVectors.csv', index=True, header=header1)
```

Then I removed

```
index_label=header1
```

And changed

```
header=True
```

to

```
`header=header1`
```

If I just did these two things I would get the error

```
ValueError: Writing 4 cols but got 5 aliases
```

So I had to remove the first column header "Dataset Number" to correct this.

[This is the resulting .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkrZ2.png)